# Google Sheets ignoring url links

Tags: google, import, delimiter

I don't know if this is the right place for this questions, but I'm stuck..  I'm trying to upload a product to google marketplace.  It says I can do it with google sheets.  two fields require a URL.  when I import my tab delimed text file into the sheet, everything goes in just fine, except the URL fields.  It's like it just completely ignores them.  I don't get an error message at all.  Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: one thing I tried to fix this that did work was.. instead of just importing the URLs in the fields, I tried importing `=IMPORTDATA("https://www.example.com") `  that didn't work either

Comment: I also just tried importing `=HYPERLINK("https://www.example.com", "link")`